# NodeJS create CSV write directly to Google Storage

Tags: javascript, node.js, csv, google-app-engine, google-cloud-storage

I've tried to tackle this a few different ways but am coming up dry.  There are many csv converters, but they all seem to write to a local file (which is not allowed on the app engine).  I would like to write the file directly to google storage bucket.

Very simply...

```
app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  var writer = csvWriter()
  writer.pipe(fs.createWriteStream('out.csv')); // bucket.upload('out.csv);
  writer.write({hello: "world", foo: "bar", baz: "taco"})
  writer.end();
});`
```

Answer (score 0):

Nailed it...

```
const blob = bucket.file('file.csv');
const blobStream = blob.createWriteStream({
  resumable: false,
});

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  var writer = csvWriter();
  writer.pipe(blobStream);
  writer.write({hello: "world", foo: "bar", baz: "taco"})
  writer.end();
  res.end();
});
```